# AWS CDK: Cognito with ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'd like to secure my webapp running in an ECS Fargate container with Cognito. Using the convenient `ecspatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` with the Cognito example given at `AuthenticateCognitoAction` shown at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-actions.AuthenticateCognitoAction.html is giving me a headache.

I've tried to first create the `LoadBalancer` shown in the Cognito example and then pass it as the `loadBalancer` parameter in `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` constructor. And I've also tried first creating the `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` and then doing `fargateService.loadBalancer.addListener` to add the Cognito Listener. Both solutions fail with:

```
Resource handler returned message: "A listener already exists on this port for this load balancer
```

What's the correct way of combining these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this [demo stack](https://github.com/MauriceBrg/cognito-alb-fargate-demo/blob/master/infrastructure/demo_stack.py) I found that you:

1. create the Cognito User Pool and Client
2. create `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`
3. add a `AuthenticateCognitoAction` to the fargateService listener like this:

```
    fargateService.listener.addAction('Listener', {
      action: new actions.AuthenticateCognitoAction({
        userPool,
        userPoolClient,
        userPoolDomain,
        next: elbv2.ListenerAction.forward([fargateService.targetGroup]),
      }),
    })
```